Troubles with Ubuntu boot
Recently I found my old laptop Compaq Presario CQ61 from 2010 and decided to install Linux on it. Firstly I installed SSD. After it Ive installed Ubuntu and thats how it was booting: laptop shows logo and after it I only see black screen with white line blinking on top left for 4 minutes, and only after it I see Ubuntu logo and booting to user choose menu.
I tried to install Windows on it and I also see this white line on the top but only for 2-3 frames and Windows logo just after that. It fully boots within 20 seconds.
After it Ive installed Kubuntu and now it boots at 1 minute only when I tapping Enter button all the time after laptop logo. It way better than 4 minutes but I really want to laptop boot on its own.
Im seeking for any advice, should I change something in bios? please feel free to ask for any additional information
May a problem be in the fact it use noveau driver? My GPU is G 103M and needs 340 ver of Nvidia driver and its last version is for 5.4 kernel while Im on 6.8.

If 2010, it should be BIOS only. And that old the noveau driver should be ok. Did you install Ubuntu or Kubuntu. I use Kubuntu and was able to boot it on my 2006 laptop from an external SSD. But I had tuned that install by removing all snaps and making other changes. While link is 20.04, I did same changes to 22.04 & to 24.04. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Your Compaq Presario CQ61's hardware should be able to run Ubuntu and it does, but its low performance is at least partially due to its weak hardware.
