Kubuntu 24.04: boot takes forever
Since a few weeks (I can't pin down when the problem started occurring exactly) booting my system takes forever, at least compared to the before-state.
The logs while booting show
2024-07-15T00:38:56.074118+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)

before the big delay happens (1m and 3s).
Here's what I believe to be the relevant portion of my kernel.log (the two lines concerning ucsi_acpi which here are technically the last before the delay are just due to a troublesome USB device, when removed the behavior doesn't change) as well as all the other logs:
2024-07-15T00:38:55.752966+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: snd_hda_intel 0000:00:1f.3: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_audio_component_bind_ops [i915])
2024-07-15T00:38:55.762049+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: fbcon: i915drmfb (fb0) is primary device
2024-07-15T00:38:55.762094+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: fbcon: Deferring console take-over
2024-07-15T00:38:55.762096+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] fb0: i915drmfb frame buffer device
2024-07-15T00:38:55.785997+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0: autoconfig for ALC289: line_outs=2 (0x14/0x17/0x0/0x0/0x0) type:speaker
2024-07-15T00:38:55.786003+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    speaker_outs=0 (0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
2024-07-15T00:38:55.786004+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    hp_outs=1 (0x21/0x0/0x0/0x0/0x0)
2024-07-15T00:38:55.786004+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    mono: mono_out=0x0
2024-07-15T00:38:55.786004+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:    inputs:
2024-07-15T00:38:55.786005+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headset Mic=0x19
2024-07-15T00:38:55.786005+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Headphone Mic=0x1b
2024-07-15T00:38:55.786006+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: snd_hda_codec_realtek hdaudioC0D0:      Internal Mic=0x12
2024-07-15T00:38:55.925974+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for firmware download to complete
2024-07-15T00:38:55.925982+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware loaded in 1605085 usecs
2024-07-15T00:38:55.925983+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Waiting for device to boot
2024-07-15T00:38:55.941968+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Device booted in 15587 usecs
2024-07-15T00:38:55.941970+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Malformed MSFT vendor event: 0x02
2024-07-15T00:38:55.950978+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Found Intel DDC parameters: intel/ibt-0040-0041.ddc
2024-07-15T00:38:55.951969+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Applying Intel DDC parameters completed
2024-07-15T00:38:55.954982+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware timestamp 2023.48 buildtype 1 build 75324
2024-07-15T00:38:55.954983+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware SHA1: 0x23bac558
2024-07-15T00:38:56.031037+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: MGMT ver 1.22
2024-07-15T00:38:56.034994+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: NET: Registered PF_ALG protocol family
2024-07-15T00:38:56.074118+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: hci0: Bad flag given (0x1) vs supported (0x0)
2024-07-15T00:38:56.487075+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH Headphone Mic as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input36
2024-07-15T00:38:56.487080+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input37
2024-07-15T00:38:56.487081+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input38
2024-07-15T00:38:56.487082+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input39
2024-07-15T00:38:56.487082+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: input: HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input40
2024-07-15T00:38:57.479009+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: unknown error 0
2024-07-15T00:38:57.479013+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: ucsi_acpi USBC000:00: UCSI_GET_PDOS failed (-5)
2024-07-15T00:39:00.170470+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: fbcon: Taking over console
2024-07-15T00:39:00.193162+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Console: switching to colour frame buffer device 240x75
2024-07-15T00:39:55.240044+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WRT: Invalid buffer destination
2024-07-15T00:39:55.279986+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: kauditd_printk_skb: 158 callbacks suppressed
2024-07-15T00:39:55.279996+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: audit: type=1400 audit(1720996795.278:169): apparmor="DENIED" operation="capable" class="cap" profile="/usr/sbin/cupsd" pid=1615 comm="cupsd" capability=12  capname="net_admin"
2024-07-15T00:39:55.393989+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_UMAC_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x20
2024-07-15T00:39:55.394001+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_LMAC2_PD_NOTIFICATION: 0x1f
2024-07-15T00:39:55.394002+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0: 0x90
2024-07-15T00:39:55.394003+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: CNVI_SCU_SEQ_DATA_DW9: 0x0
2024-07-15T00:39:55.394976+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: RFIm is deactivated, reason = 4
2024-07-15T00:39:55.486984+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Registered PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0
2024-07-15T00:39:55.807982+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
2024-07-15T00:39:55.807993+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
2024-07-15T00:39:55.807994+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
2024-07-15T00:39:58.922061+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: wlp0s20f3: 80 MHz not supported, disabling VHT
2024-07-15T00:39:58.930111+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: wlp0s20f3: authenticate with c8:0e:14:f4:c2:52 (local address=70:a8:d3:96:3a:bb)
2024-07-15T00:39:58.931017+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: wlp0s20f3: send auth to c8:0e:14:f4:c2:52 (try 1/3)
2024-07-15T00:39:58.964022+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: wlp0s20f3: authenticated
2024-07-15T00:39:58.964025+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: wlp0s20f3: associate with c8:0e:14:f4:c2:52 (try 1/3)
2024-07-15T00:39:58.974303+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: wlp0s20f3: RX AssocResp from c8:0e:14:f4:c2:52 (capab=0x1431 status=0 aid=9)
2024-07-15T00:39:58.985139+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: wlp0s20f3: associated
2024-07-15T00:39:59.035976+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: wlp0s20f3: Limiting TX power to 20 (20 - 0) dBm as advertised by c8:0e:14:f4:c2:52
2024-07-15T00:39:59.889976+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: rfkill: input handler disabled
2024-07-15T00:40:00.396978+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: usb 3-9: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
2024-07-15T00:40:06.846980+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: usb 3-9: reset full-speed USB device number 4 using xhci_hcd
2024-07-15T00:40:15.388974+02:00 kubuntu-leptop kernel: rfkill: input handler enabled

Note the delay between 2024-07-15T00:38:57.479013+02:00 and 2024-07-15T00:39:00.170470+02:00.
➜  ~ systemd-analyze
Startup finished in 1min 25.222s (firmware) + 6.087s (loader) + 2.351s (kernel) + 1min 8.903s (userspace) = 2min 42.565s 
graphical.target reached after 1min 8.887s in userspace.

➜  ~ systemd-analyze blame
1min 48.208s fstrim.service
  1min 634ms thermald.service
  1min 633ms gpu-manager.service
  1min 623ms snapd.seeded.service
  1min 575ms NetworkManager.service
  1min 379ms upower.service
     55.419s plocate-updatedb.service
      5.824s plymouth-quit-wait.service
      3.958s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      2.406s fwupd.service
      2.091s systemd-suspend.service
      1.334s nvidia-persistenced.service
      1.242s nvidia-suspend.service
       472ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       456ms snapd.apparmor.service
       442ms systemd-binfmt.service
       433ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
       376ms dev-nvme1n1p2.device
       352ms boot-efi.mount
       340ms snapd.service
       265ms dev-loop30.device
       233ms accounts-daemon.service
       225ms dev-loop29.device
       224ms dev-loop28.device
       199ms dev-loop6.device
       196ms dev-loop5.device
       195ms dev-loop0.device
       193ms udisks2.service
       190ms dev-loop7.device
       190ms dev-loop3.device
       189ms dev-loop2.device
       182ms apport.service
       177ms dev-loop4.device
       172ms systemd-backlight@leds:dell::kbd_backlight.service
       159ms e2scrub_reap.service
       151ms dev-loop27.device
       148ms dev-loop9.device
       148ms dev-loop26.device
       142ms user@1000.service
       141ms fwupd-refresh.service
       136ms networkd-dispatcher.service
       126ms systemd-journal-flush.service
       113ms gnome-remote-desktop.service
       110ms update-notifier-download.service
       108ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
       106ms rsyslog.service
        93ms iio-sensor-proxy.service
        92ms dpkg-db-backup.service
        89ms systemd-resolved.service
        88ms power-profiles-daemon.service
        87ms gdm.service
        86ms polkit.service
        85ms avahi-daemon.service
        84ms bluetooth.service
        79ms dev-loop1.device
        77ms dbus.service
        71ms dev-loop20.device
        71ms dev-loop25.device
        68ms dev-loop21.device
        67ms dev-loop22.device
        67ms usbguard.service
        66ms smartmontools.service
        66ms dev-loop24.device
        66ms dev-loop18.device
        65ms dev-loop23.device
        65ms ModemManager.service
        65ms dev-loop19.device
        65ms switcheroo-control.service
        65ms dev-loop16.device
        64ms dev-loop17.device
        63ms dev-loop15.device
        63ms dev-loop14.device
        62ms dev-loop13.device
        62ms usbguard-dbus.service
        61ms dev-loop11.device
        60ms dev-loop10.device
        60ms systemd-timesyncd.service
        59ms dev-loop12.device
        59ms dev-loop8.device
        56ms apparmor.service
        54ms systemd-logind.service
        52ms systemd-random-seed.service
        48ms systemd-udevd.service
        46ms secureboot-db.service
        45ms plymouth-start.service
        44ms snap-bare-5.mount
        44ms snap-blender-4786.mount
        42ms snap-core18-2823.mount
        42ms logrotate.service
        38ms snap-core18-2829.mount
        37ms snap-core20-2318.mount
        37ms snap-core22-1122.mount
        35ms snap-core22-1380.mount
        34ms snap-dbgate-438.mount
        34ms systemd-remount-fs.service
        34ms snap-firefox-4451.mount
        33ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-3259\x2d845A.service
        33ms systemd-journald.service
        32ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
        32ms snap-firefox-4483.mount
        31ms keyboard-setup.service
        31ms snap-fusion360-33.mount
        30ms bolt.service
        30ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d28\x2d1804-198.mount
        30ms systemd-modules-load.service
        29ms snap-gnome\x2d3\x2d38\x2d2004-143.mount
        29ms cups.service
        28ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-141.mount
        27ms snap-gnome\x2d42\x2d2204-176.mount
        26ms snap-gtk\x2dcommon\x2dthemes-1535.mount
        25ms snap-kf5\x2d5\x2d111\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d15\x2d11\x2dcore22-7.mount
        24ms snap-kf5\x2d5\x2d113\x2dqt\x2d5\x2d15\x2d11\x2dcore22-1.mount
        23ms snap-postman-254.mount
        22ms snap-r\x2dquick\x2dshare-x1.mount
        21ms grub-initrd-fallback.service
        21ms wpa_supplicant.service
        21ms snap-snapd-21465.mount
        20ms colord.service
        20ms snap-snapd-21759.mount
        19ms snap-thunderbird-482.mount
        19ms snap-thunderbird-490.mount
        18ms snap-tio-1157.mount
        17ms snap-tio-1172.mount
        16ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d9\x2ddevel\x2dcore22-20.mount
        16ms snapd.socket
        15ms grub-common.service
        15ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2d9\x2ddevel\x2dcore22-21.mount
        14ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime\x2dcore22-74.mount
        14ms plymouth-read-write.service
        14ms snap-wine\x2dplatform\x2druntime\x2dcore22-75.mount
        13ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev-early.service
        13ms snap-xournalpp-94.mount
        13ms kerneloops.service
        12ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
        12ms var-snap-firefox-common-host\x2dhunspell.mount
        12ms rtkit-daemon.service
        11ms dev-hugepages.mount
        10ms dev-mqueue.mount
        10ms systemd-rfkill.service
        10ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
         9ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
         9ms systemd-sysctl.service
         9ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
         9ms modprobe@loop.service
         8ms alsa-restore.service
         8ms systemd-update-utmp.service
         8ms kmod-static-nodes.service
         8ms modprobe@configfs.service
         8ms nvidia-resume.service
         7ms modprobe@drm.service
         7ms systemd-user-sessions.service
         7ms modprobe@fuse.service
         7ms modprobe@dm_mod.service
         6ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
         5ms console-setup.service
         4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         4ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
         4ms ufw.service
         3ms swapfile.swap
         3ms sys-kernel-config.mount
         2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         1ms setvtrgb.service

➜  ~ systemd-analyze critical-chain
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @1min 8.887s
└─multi-user.target @1min 8.886s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @1min 3.062s +5.824s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @1min 3.046s +7ms
      └─network.target @1min 3.034s
        └─NetworkManager.service @2.455s +1min 575ms
          └─dbus.service @2.374s +77ms
            └─basic.target @2.349s
              └─sockets.target @2.349s
                └─cups.socket @2.519s
                  └─sysinit.target @2.331s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @1min 3.127s +12ms
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @2.157s
                        └─system.slice @189ms
                          └─-.slice @189ms


I also used these steps on Kubuntu 22.04 & 24.04. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster & https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2496312&p=14183456#post14183456 Going to test my changes in 24.10 development version shortly.  something stange on output of systemd-analyze as it says 46min (it was not) and then graphical.target reached after 4.102s in userspace

The issue seems to have kind of fixed itself, I didn't really do anything obvious that could've been the solution.
Here's a list of things I did I'd say could've possibly been what ended up fixing it:

I updated to Davinci Resolve Studio to the latest stable release (after this change I first noticed the issue was resolved)
I upgraded all packages (sudo apt-get update as well as sudo apt-get upgrade)
I ran sudo apt-get autoremove

I'm sorry in case you are encountering a similar problem and looking for a solution, I hope these steps help.
