Why is Ubuntu 24.04's boot time is so slow in dual boot?
After I upgraded Ubuntu from 23.10 to 24.04, its boot time slowed down. Every time I turn on my computer, I have to wait 2-3 minutes. I think it is too slow. I have a dual boot(ubuntu and Windows) installed. I tried many methods, but none of them worked. How to solve this slowing down problem of boot? The "Timed out waiting for udev queue being empty" error sometimes raises.
RAM: 32 GB
SSD: 1T
Swap memory: 52 GB

systemd-analyze blame
The result of the above command.
11.286s plymouth-quit-wait.service
10.235s gpu-manager.service
6.355s postgresql@16-main.service
4.959s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
2.068s NetworkManager.service
2.031s thermald.service
1.130s snapd.seeded.service
981ms fwupd.service
942ms snapd.service
841ms docker.service
822ms systemd-resolved.service
788ms systemd-oomd.service
778ms systemd-binfmt.service
778ms systemd-timesyncd.service
722ms snapd.apparmor.service
466ms dev-nvme0n1p9.device
411ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
406ms apport.service
370ms user@1000.service
244ms dev-loop3.device
239ms dev-loop7.device
238ms dev-loop2.device
237ms containerd.service
228ms rsyslog.service

systemd-analyze critical-chain
The result of the above command
graphical.target @16.417s
└─multi-user.target @16.417s
  └─plymouth-quit-wait.service @5.027s +11.387s
    └─systemd-user-sessions.service @5.009s +14ms
      └─network.target @4.989s
        └─NetworkManager.service @2.929s +2.059s
          └─dbus.service @2.676s +244ms
            └─basic.target @2.620s
              └─sockets.target @2.620s
                └─snapd.socket @2.619s +708us
                  └─sysinit.target @2.603s
                    └─systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service @3.270s +15ms
                      └─system-systemd\x2dbacklight.slice @3.251s
                        └─system.slice @437ms
                          └─-.slice @437ms

I would be happy, if any one of you fixed this issue.
If You need any system info, feel free to ask.
I tried to disable the above services that slowed down my system. But not worked

Please also post the output of systemd-analyze critical-chain

This adds up to less then 1 min.

While this says 20.04, I did same for 22.04 and 24.04. But only some changes depending on computer. Older one does not have bluetooth nor Thunderbolt, so exclude those. I do not use snaps on any system, so remove snaps & install Firefox & Thunderbird from ppa. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster If you do not have SSD or NVMe, those can make a huge difference in boot time.

I have edited my question adding the result  of systemd-analyze critical-chain

Suspend time is also slow
