Ubuntu 22.04 Slow boot (udisks2.service in particular)
Recently my computer (Ubuntu 22.04) has started to boot slowly after no particular or drastic change (though have been leaving it on suspend for about a week). This is a PC I've build around 3 years ago and has only displayed this issue since last week. After digging around a bit, it seems that snaps were contributing to the issue, so I removed all snaps and replaced them with flathub equivalents. It seems to boot a little faster now, but it's still rather slow.
Running systemd-analyze blame returns the following:
31.139s udisks2.service
 3.454s grub-initrd-fallback.service
 2.380s fwupd.service
 1.860s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 1.382s postfix@-.service
  877ms ua-timer.service
  675ms docker.socket
  536ms docker.service
  227ms systemd-resolved.service
  219ms dev-nvme0n1p5.device
  162ms networkd-dispatcher.service
  156ms cups.service
  140ms containerd.service
  131ms systemd-timesyncd.service
  120ms user@1000.service
  101ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
  100ms accounts-daemon.service
   83ms binfmt-support.service
   79ms systemd-binfmt.service
   79ms apparmor.service
   76ms bluetooth.service
   69ms systemd-journald.service
   69ms apport-autoreport.service
   65ms ModemManager.service
   62ms systemd-logind.service
   62ms update-notifier-download.service
   57ms mnt-4A24\x2d69B8.mount
   57ms proc-sys-fs-binfmt_misc.mount
   56ms gdm.service
   50ms upower.service
   48ms apport.service
   48ms systemd-udevd.service
   47ms secureboot-db.service
   46ms NetworkManager.service
   44ms mnt-ab8293ba\x2d79af\x2d4031\x2db5cc\x2de12ccae430ef.mount
   44ms avahi-daemon.service
   40ms gpu-manager.service
   39ms boot-efi.mount
   38ms polkit.service
   35ms keyboard-setup.service
   34ms switcheroo-control.service
   31ms e2scrub_reap.service
   28ms systemd-modules-load.service
   23ms packagekit.service
   22ms systemd-remount-fs.service
   20ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
   20ms thermald.service
   19ms alsa-restore.service
   18ms systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service
   18ms rsyslog.service
   18ms colord.service
   17ms wpa_supplicant.service
   17ms mnt-ata\x2dKIOXIA\x2dEXCERIA_SATA_SSD_50CC119QE541.mount
   14ms plymouth-read-write.service
   14ms kerneloops.service
   12ms dev-hugepages.mount
   12ms console-setup.service
   12ms dev-mqueue.mount
   11ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
   11ms systemd-update-utmp.service
   10ms sys-kernel-tracing.mount
   10ms systemd-sysctl.service
    8ms ubuntu-fan.service
    8ms systemd-sysusers.service
    7ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
    7ms kmod-static-nodes.service
    7ms grub-common.service
    7ms modprobe@configfs.service
    7ms modprobe@drm.service
    6ms modprobe@fuse.service
    6ms systemd-fsck-root.service
    5ms systemd-random-seed.service
    5ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
    5ms systemd-user-sessions.service
    5ms user-runtime-dir@1000.service
    5ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
    4ms openvpn.service
    4ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-2F70\x2dAC33.service
    3ms systemd-journal-flush.service
    3ms systemd-rfkill.service
    3ms swapfile.swap
    3ms rtkit-daemon.service
    3ms ufw.service
    3ms setvtrgb.service
    2ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
    2ms modprobe@efi_pstore.service
    2ms sys-kernel-config.mount
    1ms postfix.service

While running systemd-analyze critical-chain returns the following:
The time when unit became active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit took to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @33.409s
└─udisks2.service @2.269s +31.139s
  └─basic.target @1.391s
    └─sockets.target @1.391s
      └─docker.socket @715ms +675ms
        └─sysinit.target @710ms
          └─systemd-timesyncd.service @578ms +131ms
            └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service @510ms +20ms
              └─local-fs.target @487ms
                └─run-user-1000-doc.mount @33.563s
                  └─run-user-1000.mount @3.617s
                    └─local-fs-pre.target @269ms
                      └─systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service @261ms +7ms
                        └─systemd-sysusers.service @252ms +8ms
                          └─systemd-remount-fs.service @226ms +22ms
                            └─systemd-fsck-root.service @217ms +6ms
                              └─systemd-journald.socket @207ms
                                └─system.slice @195ms
                                  └─-.slice @195ms

Any suggestions as to what might be causing this and to how to shorten the boot time?

Some things to review. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster I still use same settings on 24.10. Trying to mount corrupted or encrypted partitions, so it has to time out? disable unused devices:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/586715/speeding-up-udisks2-service-in-linux
Also system indexer wants udisks2 https://community.kde.org/Baloo/Configuration

I didn't have any time to work on this problem yesterday, so nothing's changed, but somehow today I booted my PC only for it to boot fast.
I ran system-analyze blame only to see 138ms udisks2.service, which is....odd.
