Issue to boot into ubuntu new build PC
I have issue to boot into Ubuntu 24.10 on my new PC (no dual boot).
My hardware setup:

Motherboard ASUS ROG STRIX Z790-F Gaming WiFi
CPU Intel 14900K
RAM Crutial Pro DDR5 6000MHz
SSD Samsung 980 LVM

I have updated motherboard`s firmware, but every boot takes 2 mins, then I get BIOS safe mode and after explicitly choosing my ssd (F1 -> F8 to choose boot media) it boots into ubuntu. SSD with boot partition is visible in BIOS, secure boot -> custom (that means off). I tried grub-install and sudo update-grub did not work for me.
could you help me, can provide with additional information if needed!

May have hints here: Asus Proart z790 Creator WIFI motherboard
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2501185
ASUS PRIME Z790-P WIFI motherboard.
https://www.phoronix.com/review/intel-14600k-14900k-linux Run Boot-Repair and link to its report. I still use these same tweaks to improve boot speed in 22.04 & 24.04. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

I have previously encountered the same issue you are experiencing. Please consider the following recommendations to address the problem:

Prioritize the '/boot' Partition:
Access your motherboard settings and ensure that the '/boot' partition is listed before the other partitions. This prioritization can facilitate a smoother boot process.

Enable Compatibility Support Module (CSM) in BIOS:
Enter the BIOS setup and enable the Compatibility Support Module (CSM). Enabling CSM can enhance compatibility with various hardware and software configurations, potentially resolving boot-related issues.

Utilize BootRepair for Boot Problems:
BootRepair has proven to be an effective solution in the event of a boot malfunction. To use BootRepair:

Create a live Ubuntu USB or CD.
Boot your system using the live Ubuntu environment.
Run BootRepair and follow the on-screen instructions to repair the boot configuration.




Is this an AI generated answer?

No, I just tried to explain it well.
