boot taking too much time
Earlier I had dual boot  ( Windows 10 + Ubuntu 24.04 ), which booted fast. Recently, I cleared the Windows partition and installed Ubuntu, but found out that now booting takes too much time. What can be done and how do I troubleshoot?
Using systemd-analyze gives the below result:
> systemd-analyze 
Startup finished in 10.413s (firmware) + 12.542s (loader) + 7.531s (kernel) + 26.536s (userspace) = 57.024s 
graphical.target reached after 26.511s in userspace.

update
> systemd-analyze  blame

51.204s apt-daily.service
20.255s plymouth-quit-wait.service
 5.033s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
 2.783s fwupd.service
 1.695s plymouth-read-write.service
 1.166s logrotate.service
 1.008s NetworkManager.service
  843ms snapd.seeded.service
  742ms systemd-suspend.service
  626ms boot-efi.mount
  553ms snapd.service
  489ms systemd-journal-flush.service
  459ms apport.service
  389ms man-db.service
  333ms udisks2.service
  333ms dev-nvme0n1p6.device
  274ms gnome-remote-desktop.service


Some things to review here, plus links to more. I still make these changes in 22.04 & 24.04. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Thanks but suggestions are like removing snap packages are not applicable in my case.

$ systemd-analyze  blame  ?  Note edit your posting and add the FIRST (e.g. 10) lines of the text there, with code formatting.

Does it help if you run sudo update-grub?

@Hannu updated the question with what you have suggested

Well, the top most time consuming thing is:

51.204s apt-daily.service

I suggest:

Hit the Win key,
start typing Software & Updates
click or select the blue icon as it appears
Click Updates in the top of the window that opened.
Remove Daily from Automatically check for updates:
Select anything that you find reasonable,
but realize that short timeframes creates effects similar to what you have seen.

One might wish this check didn't happen at BOOT-time, but that might be hard to without some scripting at least.
A script that runs in Startup Applications (Win key again, as above to find it) might be one doable option
Actually:
#!/bin/env bash
sleep 600 # seconds
sudo apt update

... is enough, but it requires the suid bit to be set (due to sudo).
Hint: https://stackoverflow.com/a/63026866
