Long black screen between the boot start and ubuntu logo & login page
When I turn on the PC, the motherboard brand, etc. is displayed, it says that you can enter the bios by pressing F2 / DEL, after that the screen is black for 3-4 minutes, and if I press F12, I can't even see that the computer is working something, it says something like 24, but it doesn't do anything, it looks the same as when I start a command in the terminal and the machine works before it says something, then it suddenly switches to os.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Please [edit] your question and add the output (as text and not image) of the command: systemd-analyze blame | head -10.

the boot time depends upon a great many things. what processor does the computer have? how much RAM? and is the internal drive an SSD (solid-state) or an HDD (spinning disc)?
for a very old processor, i could well see Ubuntu taking several minutes to boot. and HDD's are considerably slower than SSD's - changing from an HDD to an SSD is the cheapest and easiest way to get Ubuntu booting faster.
the fact that the machine is eventually booting is a sign that you are at least on the right track.
you might also like to read this answer on stack exchange:
How can I see what happens during the boot process?
it offers a (temporary) solution to allow you to see the text output from the boot process as it is happening.

My PC has a R5 5600X RTX 4060 8GB 32GB DDR4 3200MHz RAM, 1TB Kingston KC 3000 SSD, I think it wasn't hardware limitation, or it can be?

that certainly does rule out the hardware being slow! have you tried the suggestion in the link i posted? this should allow you to see the boot process happening on screen, and (hopefully) allow you to see where things are getting bogged down.

Have you updated UEFI & SSD firmware? And do you have a boot option for Internet boot? I would make sure it is off, unless you plan on using that. Some settings that may apply. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

@robertrozee While booting in I was holding the left shift, but nothing happened, just did the same

on the machine i am sitting in front of here, i have to press f10 while booting to get into the motherboard's boot manager, select "Ubuntu" as the boot option, then repeatedly tap the RIGHT shift key to get into GRUB. from there press 'e', etc. unfortunately the exact steps may vary from machine to machine. without going through the motherboard's boot manager i can not get into GRUB.

thanks, I'm now trying to reinstall the os but is says Invalid magic number you nedd to load kernel first, it can be why it was booting slow?

from what i can tell looking online, the "invalid magic number" message is most often the result of a corrupted ISO download or a defective USB flash drive. you may wish to try another flash drive as well as re-download the Ubuntu ISO file. are you copying the ISO on a windows machine? "rufus" seems the program to use for this - i use linux exclusively and it was probably 7 years ago that i last had to copy an ISO to a flash drive on windows - i have a vague memory that i used rufus to do it back then. nearly 4am here, so heading off to bed.

one final thing, turning 'secure boot' OFF in the BIOS will help you avoid a whole load of headaches.

Thanks! Good Night!

SOLVED! I just had to take out and then put back the CMOS battery, before that I reset the bios in the bios, but it didn't work, as a test, but it did (I was on a call with one of my friends on dc and he suggested it)

excellent news! you may like to get a new CMOS battery (usually a CR2032) to replace that old one, just in case it is flat. you mentioning the battery reminded me that a few weeks back i was dealing with a computer behaving weirdly, and the cause ended up being the CMOS clock being wrong (about a year out) and this was completely messing up Ubuntu's Update Manager and the web browser.
